# GWT, AppEngine and pretty url (human url)

Tags: google-app-engine, url, gwt, clean-urls

Can anybody show a working example of how to get pretty urls on a GWT project over AppEngine.

I know that you will suggest to look at UrlRewriteFilter. I have been burning it for 3 days and get no succedd.

Please, could help?

Comment: What do you mean by "pretty URLs"?

Comment: yourdomain.com/?user=7666876&comment=adfadsf&language=english    --->awful

yourdomain.com/7666876/adfadsf/english  --> beautifull

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you're looking for: [Pretty URLs in Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297056/pretty-urls-in-google-app-engine)

Comment: I followed that link till urlrewrite filter, wich  is what i am using at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

This will work, and it's really easy:

```
def main():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler), ('/(.*)', PostHandler)], debug=True)

class PostHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, slug):
```

As explained in the article on [Pretty Urls with Google App Engine](http://www.graemeboy.com/app-engine-pretty-links)

Answer (score 0):

I followed that link till urlrewrite filter, wich  is what i am using at the moment.

I get to transform domain/?user=43434&mensage=89898 to domain/user43434-mensage89898 which is quite good for me.

But i can not transform it to domain/43434/8989.

When i try to do this i always get a fail consisting on my services cannot find an *.wgt.rpc file.

In other words, I am not able to run the next example when i use GWT:
http://zenoconsulting.wikidot.com/blog:16

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on the client side with the History class if you're willing to have a `#` at the beginning of your URLs.  In my app teachers can access their grades at http://activegrade.com/#calculus/grades, for example. The History object receives "calculus/grades" and you can parse it from there.

GWT 2.1 introduces the concept of Places -  you could look into that as well.