# how do I remap a url in gwt on appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I have a url:

http://myserver.appspot.com/service/exec?key=0AkG

how would I remap it to:

http://myserver.appspot.com/webapp.html?key=0AkG

where "key" is different every time.

Options:
1)  "*.gwt.xml" or "web.xml" - might be able to do the map, but did not find the right option - (filter looks the best bet, but requires code). 
I also tried creating a file called "exec" but it did not like the lack of the ".html" and the browser downloads the file.

2) URL re-writer. It hard to know which of these will work on GWT+GAE, did not find one yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to web.xml, it worked:

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>oldProxy</servlet-name>
<jsp-file>/proxy.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>oldProxy</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/service/exec</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

docs for:

```
  <jsp-file>
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html#1039287

Comment: Yes, this is the normal way to handle paths, but the `servlet-mapping` syntax is very limited, and you need some extra code to rewrite certain cases, or redirect crawlers etc.

Comment: This is not the most appropriate answer, why dont you select the other one?

Comment: @emecedo I selected the answer that has been confirmed as working. I know the jsp-file solution above works and was easy to setup. I did not have any luck with the URL re-writer. Manolo gave a good answer, I did upvote it. I would still be interested in confirming if GWT works with UrlRewriteFilter, or other URL re-writers.

Comment: I can confirm that Manolo's response works, I had the same problem and after reading this thread, I did follow the tutorial and my app is working with the `UrlRewriterFilter` and I have set a long list of redirections which could be impossible to maintain with .jsp's

Answer (score 0):

You need some URL re-writer.

GAE runs jetty, and it has its own [rewriter handler](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Rewrite_Handler), but since it [seems no possible to extend](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2943) their `jetty.xml` configuration for security reasons, you need to configure a filter in your `web.xml`

There are many filter examples around the Internet, but what I found easy to setup and configure is the [UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/).

You have a [tutorial](http://aaronjlynch.com/2009/11/25/url-rewriting-on-google-app-engine/) to setup the UrlRewriterFilter in GAE

Comment: Do you know if UrlRewriteFilter. works on GWT + GAE? I tried pretyfaces, but did not get it to work. A few people suggested  URL re-writers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297056/pretty-urls-in-google-app-engine/6529643#comment21174035_6529643 but is hard to know  which work on GWT + GAE.

Comment: Yes, UrlRewriteFilter works in GAE, see this: http://aaronjlynch.com/2009/11/25/url-rewriting-on-google-app-engine/

Comment: and GWT? - I suspect it was GWT that caused problems with pretyfaces.

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, GWT is browser-side JS. GWT adds a couple of server-side utilities so as it is easier for java-only projects to pass objects over the wire (RPC, RF), but there are hundreds of gwt apps working with python, ruby, php as well. I dont see any kind of interferences in server side with prettyfaces unless some sort of  classpath issue (different version of libraries, etc).